# Finding area common to two circles

Tags: geometry, circles

Having trouble finding the area common to the two mats.

> [image]

The correct answer is $99.1cm^2$

Comment: Do you think any of the ideas in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3224519/perimeter-of-two-overlapping-circles) maybe could apply to this one too?

Comment: Please [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3224551/edit) your post and add some info about what you've tried out so far.

Comment: I've just edited. Please take a look.

Comment: "With sides 12,12,16. I've calculated the angles to be 41,49,90." Isn't this a problem as an isosceles triangle must have two equal angles?

Comment: This site has useful formulas in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
Hope, it helps. I used Law of cosine and segments area formula.

Comment: My bad: in Law of Cosine $$BC^2 -  AB^2$$, they're equal so nothing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I can help you think how to solve this question leaving the calculation part for you.

> 1. Since we know that the line joining the two centres is bisected *(divided into two equal parts)*, as same radius, by the common chord. From here we can easily calculate length of the common chord using the `Pythagoras Theorem`.*(p=radius of circle, b=half of chord, h=half of distance between two centres)*
> 2. We can easily find area of the sector marked by the arc between the ends of the common chord and the radii at the two ends *(lets name it area1)*. But first we have to find the angle subtended by that arc. It is 2cos<sup>-1</sup>(h/r). *(lets name it s)*. According to formula - `area1={s/(2pie)}*r` *(note that s is in radians and pie=3.14)*. We can also find the area of the triangle formed by the common chord and the two radii at their ends. *(lets name it area2)*. `area2=hxb`.
>      Area common to the two mats is simply `2x(area1-area2)`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial, so you can make your post look nicer (e.g., \$\pi\$ produces $\pi$